# How to refresh local tab in a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, menuitem, sidebar

So I have a shiny platform with a sidebar, menuitems.
GOAL Without refreshing the whole page, I want to be able to refresh on one specific tab. 
PROBLEM So far I found how to refresh the whole page, but I just need to refresh one tab.

Tried this one
             jscode <- "shinyjs.refresh = function() { location.reload() }"
also with history(0), but it refresh the whole page.

Comment: why do you need to refresh the tab. Maybe it is a problem you can solve with some observer or reactive statement?

Comment: already tried, so I'll prefer to go with other options such as this one

Comment: Sorry @Mikael but if you can't tell us in more detail what you are trying to do, it is very hard to help you